# Hover Over Text on Action Hot-Spot Notes Client

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Designing for the Notes Client only, I am using 16x16 images for Lotusscript Action Hot-Spots. No problem with the scripts etc, but to make them user friendly I would like to a use hover-over text as in the standard Notes Popup text. I can't do this as the image is already covered by an Action Hot-Spot.

Does anyone know if this or any type of tool tip can be achieved?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: I haven't found a way yet.  Do add your own solution if you do come up with one - I'd be fascinated.

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess: a 2nd hotspot maybe?

[image: Picture Properties]

At the bottom, it would seem that one can add one or more hotspots to a picture. The Alternate Text will show up in the Status bar. It should... just my $0.02...

Comment: Yeah, thanks I tried that, you can't over lap and therefore you have to add them to the side so it doesn't work well. The product is so out of date, that is the real issue.

Comment: I know it's outdated, but it's still an excellent product (in some ways). I recently modified a form and I'm pretty sure I saw nested hotspots. Exactly how it's done I don't know, but there's a Picture hotspot inside an Action hotspot. I added an image, see above.

Comment: Thank you, but I still think I need a Hotspot Text Pop-Up don't I?